# Unable to connect to Websocket through JMeter plugins

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

My Requirement:

I have to connect to the Websocket through JMeter
Once it is connected,  I have to send some API requests having JSON data as body to the server and I have to verify the JSON response of it

Worked Items:

I have tried using Maciej Zaleski Websocket plugin but couldnt make through
I am able to connect to the websocket using Websocket open Connection but after that I am unable to send JSON data to the server
Throwing an error as

"Error: [Execution Flow] - Opening new connection - Using response message pattern "" - Using disconnect pattern "" - Waiting for the server connection for 5000 MILLISECONDS - Cannot connect to the remote server

[Variables] - Message count: 0

[Problems] - Unexpected error: null JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.ServiceSocket.sendMessage(ServiceSocket.java:189) JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler.sample(WebSocketSampler.java:141) org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Log: 2018-08-07 14:57:54,013 INFO o.e.j.w.c.WebSocketClient: Stopped org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient@35c6f96b 2018-08-07 14:57:54,014 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, local)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should switch to [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers) as the plugin you're using is abandoned for 3+ years therefore it might miss some essential functionality.

Check out [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) article for installation and usage instructions.

Comment: Thanks Dimtri, I'll try with the mentioned Sampler. I have a doubt regarding the proxy settings: The error connection timeout or couldn't connect or I/O readout error, all these errors might happen due to the default proxy settings in our properties file? If yes how can we override them.